# Duplicating html form javascript with embedded dropdown from mysql in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

After much research i learned how to duplicate part of my HTML form using javascript, it works well until i try to add php into the javascript.

The purpose of this page is for an event organiser to submit how much income each staff made through sales.

My problem is that i want the "staff name" displayed as a dropdown menu on each duplicate, this field will be retrieved from the staff table

this is my code:

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
  var record = 1;

function add_fields() {
  record++;
  var objTo = document.getElementById('staff_sales')
  var divtest = document.createElement("div");
  divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="label">Record ' + record + ':</div><div class="content"><span>Name: <select name="stock_type_id[' + record + ']">
            <?php
            $squery=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM staff") ;
            
            while ($srow=mysqli_fetch_array($squery)) {
                $sid=$srow["staff_id"];
                $sname=$srow["staff_name"];
   
                echo "<option value=\"$sid\">$sname</option>"; 
            }
            ?>
            </select>
            <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="staff_id[' + record + ']" value="" /></span><span> Sales: <input type="number" style="width:48px;" name="staff_sales[' + record + ']" value="" /></span></div>';

  objTo.appendChild(divtest)
} < /script>
```

```html
<?php include("../includes/con_db.php"); ?>

<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" name="addsales" id="addsales">
  <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
    <div>
      <tr>
        <td width="100">Date</td>
        <td>
          <input name="income_date" type="date" id="income_date" required>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100">Event</td>
        <td>
          <input name="income_event" type="text" id="income_event" required>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </div>
  </table>
  <div id="staff_sales">
    <div class='label'>Record 1:</div>
    <div class="content">


----------
This dropdown menu works fine:


      <span>Name: <select name='staff_id[]'>
            <?php
            $squery=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM staff") ;
            
            while ($srow=mysqli_fetch_array($squery)) {
                $sid=$srow["staff_id"];
                $sname=$srow["staff_name"];
   
                echo "<option value=\"$sid\">$sname</option>"; 
            }
            ?>
     </select>


----------



            <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="staff_id[]" value="" /></span>
      <span> Sales: <input type="number" style="width:48px;" name="staff_sales[]" value="" /></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  </br>
  <input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add More staff" />
  <input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Submit sales">

</form>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: any errors? what do you get? no option at all? no values/names? query is running fine? need more info here.....

Comment: without the php imbedded in javascript it works fine (except no dropdown menu obviously), when it is the form does not duplicate.

Comment: yes, you've said that already. But I'm pretty sure you get some errors in your console. Or a php-error.

Comment: do some debugging.... have you logged divtest before adding to dom? is the content alright? I bet the error is in there somewhere. A missing/wrong quotation f.e.

Comment: And I highly recommend to _first_ build the html/string and _then_ apply it to divtest.innerHTML. much easier to debug. And you're doing twice the same db-query...not so good eighter

Comment: nothing at all, just no response

Comment: then it's hard to debug... can you refactor your code (as I said before) and add some console.log's to get more information where it might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you concatenate a string in Javascript, line breaks matter. Here's a little demo:

```
<script>
//single line, works
var str_test = '<div class="label">Record ' + ' here comes a ' + '<?php echo "string from PHP" ?>' + '</div>';
console.log('str_test = ', str_test);

//multiple with + at end of line, works
str_test = '<div class="label">Record ' + ' here comes a ' + 
                '<?php echo "string from PHP" ?>' + '</div>';
console.log('str_test = ', str_test);

//does not work - string truncated as <div class="label">Record  here comes a 
str_test = '<div class="label">Record ' + ' here comes a ' 
                '<?php echo "string from PHP" ?>' + '</div>';
console.log('str_test = ', str_test);
</script>
```

Here's what I'd recommend in this case:

```
   <?php

    //first build a staff array
    $squery=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM staff") ;
    $staff = array();

    while ($srow = mysqli_fetch_array($squery)) {

        //build an array, indexed by id
        $id = $srow["staff_id"];
        $staff[$id] = $srow; 

        //build the html right into the array
        $staff[$id]['html'] = '<option value="$id">'.$srow["staff_name"].'</option>'; 
     }
    ?>
```

Then when we get into the Javascript, it's clean.

```
var html_str = '<div class="label">Record ' + record + ':</div>'+
    '<div class="content">'+
     '<span>Name: <select name="stock_type_id[' + record + ']">' +
     '<?php foreach($staff as $a){ echo $a["html"]; } ?>'+
     '</select>'+
     '<input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="staff_id[' + record + ']" value="" /></span>'+
     '<span> Sales: <input type="number" style="width:48px;" name="staff_sales[' + record + ']" value="" />' + 
     '</span></div>';

divtest.innerHTML = html_str;
//etc.... as before
```

Also, you may be missing a `<` at the beginning of this line:

```
script type = "text/javascript" >
```